# jQuery grep filtering array incorrectly for only one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am filling a table with some `json` and using a few controls to try and filter the table.  User selects 1 or all radios and then presses a filter button and the table is updated with filtered values.  This works perfectly for every key/value pair in my `json` except for one.  My `json` looks like this:

```
{
"id": "104",
"part_number": "PCF27340050",
"voltage": "400",
"noise_level": "72",
"rpm": "1420",
},
```

I have `<select>` controls for `voltage`, `rpm`, and `noise_level`.  They are being populated at runtime by grabbing distinct values from my `json` array being returned.

Here is how I'm filtering the `json`:

```
var selectedVoltage     = ($selectVoltage[0].selectedIndex > 0) ? $selectVoltage.val() : '';
var selectedMaxRPM      = ($selectMaxRPM[0].selectedIndex > 0)  ? $selectMaxRPM.val() : '';
var selectedNoiseLevel  = ($selectNoiseLevel[0].selectedIndex > 0) ? $selectNoiseLevel.val() : '';

var $filtered = $.grep(json,function(fan) {

    (selectedVoltage === ''     || fan.voltage === selectedVoltage) && 
    (selectedMaxRPM === ''      || fan.rpm  <= selectedMaxRPM) && 
    (selectedNoiseLevel === ''  || fan.noise_level <= selectedNoiseLevel);
});
```

`voltage` and `noise_level` filter exactly as expected.  `rpm` does not.  I'm trying to return everything equal to or less than the selected rpm.  But it filters only a couple values, leaving entries that have a greater value than the selected rpm.  If I change the `<=` to just `===` it works and filters the EXACT rpm value, but I want to filter everything `less than` or `equal to` <=

The only other thing I can think of that may be the problem is when I sort the `<select>` options when populating my `select` controls.  I'm doing it here:

```
//sort arrays that hold values for <select>
voltageArray.sort();
rpmArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); //this is the only array I have to sort this way, otherwise it won't sort
noiseLevelArray.sort();

//Append array values to <select>
$.each(voltageArray, function(v) {
    $selectVoltage.append('<option value="' + voltageArray[v] + '">' + voltageArray[v] + 'v</option>');
});

$.each(rpmArray, function(r) {
    $selectMaxRPM.append('<option value="' + rpmArray[r] + '">' + rpmArray[r] + ' rpm</option>');
});

$.each(noiseLevelArray, function(n) {
    $selectNoiseLevel.append('<option value="' + noiseLevelArray[n] + '">' + noiseLevelArray[n] + ' dBA</option>');
});
```

While typing this question, I noticed that if I don't use `function(a, b){return a-b}` to sort my `rpm` array, it works!  The `select` controls are sorted incorrectly, but it works.  It's sorted like this: `1100, 1120, 200, 220, 300` (sorting by first digit, not ascending by value) unless I use `function(a, b){return a-b}`.

Is there a way to fix this? Do I need to be sorting my rpm array differently?  Using just the `.sort()` function by itself lets me filter those values correctly (but my select control isn't sorted properly).  Using `.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})` breaks my filter for that field for some reason (but sorts my select control properly).

Comment: Looks like you're comparing them *as strings* instead of numbers. For example, `200` is more than `5`, but `"200"` is less than `"5"`, as `"200"` comes before `"5"` alphabetically.

Comment: Yea that's a limitation of my json unfortunately.  Is there a better way to sort numbers that are strings?

Comment: You could use the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) or just [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). For example, `+fan.rpm  <= +selectedMaxRPM`. I'd do the same for the "noise level" as well - I'd imagine the fact that it's working is strictly because you've been lucky with the values.

Comment: I'm trying parseInt() right now, converting the string to an Int as I populate the controls.  Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: That worked! I used `parseInt` when filtering and it worked perfectly!